# How to monitor consumer lag in kafka via jmx?

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka setup that includes a jmx exporter to prometheus. I'm looking for a metric, that gives the offset lag based on topic and groupid. I'm running kafka 2.2.0.

Some resources online point to a metric called `kafka.consumer`, but I have no such metric in my setup.

From my jmxterminal:

```sh
$>domains
#following domains are available
JMImplementation
com.sun.management
java.lang
java.nio
java.util.logging
jdk.management.jfr
kafka
kafka.cluster
kafka.controller
kafka.coordinator.group
kafka.coordinator.transaction
kafka.log
kafka.network
kafka.server
kafka.utils
```

I am, however, able to see the data I need by using the following command:

```sh
root@kafka-0:/kafka# bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group benchmark_consumer_group --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
Consumer group 'benchmark_consumer_group' has no active members.

TOPIC               PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
benchmark_topic_10B 2          2795128         54223220        51428092        -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 9          4               4               0               -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 6          7               7               0               -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 7          5               5               0               -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 0          2834028         54224939        51390911        -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 1          15342331        54222342        38880011        -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 4          5               5               0               -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 5          6               6               0               -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 8          8               8               0               -               -               -
benchmark_topic_10B 3          4               4               0               -               -               -
```

But that does not help since I need to track if from a metric. Also, this command takes about 25 seconds to execute, making it unreasonable to use as a source for metrics.

My guess is that the metric `kafka.consumer` does not exist in version 2.2.0 and was replaced with another. Although, I can't find any resources online with up-to-date information on how and where to get that metric

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `kafka.consumer` JMX metrics are only present on the consumer processes themselves, not on the Kafka broker processes. Note that you would not get the `kafka.consumer` metric from consumers using a consumer library other than the Java one.

Currently, there are no available JMX metrics for consumer lag from the Kafka broker itself. There are other solutions that are commonly used for monitoring consumer lag, such as [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/burrow) by LinkedIn. There are also a few open source projects such as [kafka9.offsets](https://github.com/tierhetze/kafka9.offsets) that expose consumer lag metrics via JMX, but may not be updated to work with the latest Kafka.

Comment: What you're saying is very unlikely to be true, considering that I did query the broker using the script `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` while there were no consumers connected, and got the data. See my question, the output is there

Comment: Correct, you will see consumer group lag in `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` output. This, internally, calculates the lag via the `__consumer_offsets` topic. Although you can see metrics such as lag from the command line tools, it does not mean that the metrics are exposed via JMX from the broker.

Comment: Oh ok got it. Is there a way to perform the same calculations `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` does in a quicker way? The script takes 25s to run. If I can get the same result in under a second, I'll be able to send this data to prometheus by myself (no need for jmx)

Comment: @Tom As mentioned, Burrow will consume the offsets topic, and you could combine that with Telegraf, which has a scraper for Burrow (assuming Burrow doesn't do Prometheus metrics) for pushing those values into a metrics store

Comment: @Tom there's also this project https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora/issues/58

Comment: I've already seen Burrow, and it looks good. However, for now, there's a strategic decision to avoid adding complexity to the system, and stay only with what is available out of the box. So I'm just looking for a way to query kafka for the offset lag for each consumer group per topic

Comment: @TomKlino I would suggest checking out this project; it looks like it does what you're looking for and as it's open source, you could modify it to your liking. https://github.com/braedon/prometheus-kafka-consumer-group-exporter

Answer (score 7):

You can give Kafka Minion ( https://github.com/cloudworkz/kafka-minion ) a try. While Kafka Minion internally works similiarly as Burrow (consumes __consumer_offsets topic for Consumer Group Offsets) it has several advantages for your use case

**Advantages of Kafka Minion over Burrow for your case:**

- Has native prometheus support (no additional deployment necessary to just expose metrics to prometheus)
- Has a sample Grafana dashboard
- Has additional metrics (such as last commit timestamp for a consumergroup:topic:partition combination, commitrates, info about cleanup policy, you can list all consumer groups for a given topic, etc)
- No zookeeper dependency included (which also means that consumers who still commit offsets to zookeeper are not supported)
- High Availability support (!!). Burrow has the problem that it will always expose metrics, which will be wrong when it just has started consuming the __consumer_offsets topic. Therefore you cannot run it in a HA mode. This is a problem when you want to setup alerts based on consumer group lags
- Kafka Minion does not support multiple clusters, which reduces complexity in code and as enduser. You can obviously still deploy Kafka Minion per cluster

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of Kafka Minion, and I am still looking for more feedback from other users. I intend to actively maintain and develop the exporter for my projects, the company I am working for and for the community.

To answer your question regarding what you are seeing using the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` shell script. This won't work as it cannot report lags for inactive consumers which is a bit counterproductive.

Comment: would ne nice to have support for kerberized kafka clusters

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya We are working on it, PR is comming soon. Review and testing is appreciated. There's an open github issue, lets discuss there

Comment: @kentor I am trying to integrate Minions with AWS MSK , here is the link could you please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61641056/kakfa-minions-with-aws-msk