# Kakfa Minions with AWS MSK

Tags: apache-kafka

I was going through [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559905/how-to-monitor-consumer-lag-in-kafka-via-jmx#), kafka minions looked like promising solution for monitoring kafka lag. I have MSK with SSL but not username/password, however in Kakfa minions with TLS looks like key,username  & password are mandatory. I can connect to MSK with burrow using following configuration which works fine, I am not able to figure out how to make Kakfa minions work with MSK. Any help is appreciated.

```
 [tls.mytlsprofile]

    cafile="P1/cacerts"

    noverify=true
```

Comment: AWS Cloudwatch should be able to get lag as well...

Comment: In Kafka Minion you can also pass just a CA certificate to use intermediate certificates. What error message does it show if pass TLS certificates and SASL enabled? Feel free to submit an issue in the repo. I think Kafka Minion is too small that you would get any help here via StackOverflow